# Kawamata covering lemma - question on the branch divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a non-singular projective variety over the field of complex numbers, of dimension $\geq 2$. Suppose $D$ is a non-singular and irreducible divisor of $X$.

The Kawamata covering lemma (Proposition 4.1.12, Positivity in Algebraic Geometry) says that - for any $m>0$, there is a smooth variety $Y$ and a finite flat morphism $f:Y\rightarrow X$ such that $f^*D=mD'$ for some smooth divisor $D'$ in $Y$.

(a) Looking at the proof, it seems to me that the divisor $D'$ is irreducible as well. Is this right?

(b) Is $f$ a Galois morphism? I think it is, since it is constructed from the Bloch-Gieseker covering and cyclic covering.

(c) Consider the morphism between non-singular irreducible varieties $f|_{D'}:D'\rightarrow D$. Can we say what the degree of this map is? Is it possible to obtain a covering $f$ so that $f|_{D'}$ is of some prescribed degree?

Comment: If you take ramification locus in $X$ is nc , then there is such $f$ I think

Comment: @HassanJolany, if $D$ is irreducible and if  $f^*D =mD'$, then $D'$ is smooth by the statement of Kawamata covering lemma. Hence $D'$ cannot be a normal crossing divisor right. It is either irreducible and smooth, or it is a disjoint union of smooth irreducible components right?

Comment: Ahh, I had assumed $D$ is snc

Comment: @HassanJolany, so in the case when $D$ is irreducible, $f^*D_{red}$ will be irreducible?

Comment: I think it can be reduced

Comment: @HassanJolany, you mean it can have multiple components?

Comment: See section 3 http://repository.ias.ac.in/3445/1/3445.pdf

Comment: @HassanJolany, I just did. It says if $D$ is a normal crossing divisor, then $(f^*D)_{red}$ is also one. It does not seem to mention anything about the reduced pullbacks of irreducible components.

Comment: When you extend field of char=p , then from Theorem 7.6. of page 84 , http://www.math.uiuc.edu/documenta/vol-20/vol-20-all.pdf

Comment: @HassanJolany, this again talks about a NC? Can we say something about reduced pullbacks of irreducible components?